# UIButtons appear below the view that they are placed on top of when on a 64 bit system

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, 64-bit

**BACKGROUND**

I have a view hierarchy:

[image]

... and it looks like this in the UI preview:

[image]

Each button is composed of an icon (the "image" property) and a background image (the "background" property). The background image is basically a resizable bevel frame which combined with the underlaying UIImageView (ButtonPanel) gives the button its final look.

Then I have a piece of code in a custom segue (leading to this controller) that inserts a screen sized view at index 0 in the controller's view hierarchy:

```
background.tag = NSIntegerMax;
[[self.destinationViewController view] insertSubview:background atIndex:0];
```

Now this has worked well and without any problems... until I changed architectures to include arm64 (64 bit) and ran it on a 64 bit device.

---

**PROBLEM**

When running the app on a 64-bit system, the following things happen:

- Only the graphics of the button in the middle are visible.
- Remaining buttons appear as if they would be hidden or placed below ButtonPanel, however they are not (verified in debugger). Instead the graphics render below ButtonPanel (verified by offsetting ButtonPanel a bit vertically).
- If I move the middle button so that x < 64 points, then its graphics also disappear (the corresponding thing happens if I move it to the right and its right edge is closer than 64 points from the right screen edge).
- If I remove the insertSubview:atIndex: call, then everything works as expected.

Here are some images illustrating the problem:

[image]

(only middle button visible)

[image]

(same as above but with ButtonPanel offset vertically by -19 points)

---

**MORE INFO**

The following steps have been taken in order to close in on the root of the bug:

- I have made sure that all participating views have tag = 0;
- All IBOutlets related to the buttons have been temporarily removed;
- All other views that were not necessary to reproduce this bug have been temporarily removed;
- Replacing the insertSubview:atIndex with insertSubview:belowSubview or addSubview: does not help;

Other potentially relevant details:

- The project uses autoresizing masks thoroughly (no auto layout and no universal storyboard);
- Deployment target is "6.0";
- I have converted the project to 64-bit following the Apple guidelines at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html
- I have failed to reproduce this bug in a fresh project, thus I cannot provide any project file to look into at the moment.

---

**UPDATE (2015-03-16)**

I have now found the root of the problem. The "background" variable in the quoted code is in fact an UIImageView whose image property is set using a rendered screenshot. The screenshot is rendered using the following method:

```
- (UIImage*) createImageOfView:(UIView*)view withSize:(CGSize)size {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, [view isOpaque], view.window.screen.scale);
    CGContextRef const context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage* const image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

<del>**I have identified that the whole problem is related to calling UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions in this method.**</del> But it only happens if the UIImageView containing the image is inserted into the view hierarchy (i.e. simply rendering the screenshot does NOT cause the problem in question).

I have now tried to assign an image from the asset cataglog, and the same problem occurs. Thus it's only when the UIImageView's image property is nil that everything works as expected; setting the image property to any valid image introduces the problem in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved! After a total of 10 hours...
Anyway, here's what happened.

The inserted background view did, before being inserted into the view hierarchy as mentioned in the question, participate in a custom segue animation. This animation was a "horizontal flip over". However, I forgot to reset the transformations used for this transition. Thus the effective width of the background view was basically zero (2.84217e-14). And inserting a view with zero width into the view hierarchy apparently results in weird behaviour on the 64 bit architecture.

Initially I tried to force-change the frame, but when the frame didn't respond to that, it led my thoughts to the transition animations. So, what solved this whole problem was adding the following lines of code in the final animation completion block:

```
fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
```

... where fromView is the "background" view from above.